# jQuery- If array matches to variable then push it to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create new array from array like this

```
myArray = [
["9-15", "Text"],
["9-15", "Text"],
["8-15", "Text"],
]
```

If is selected value equal to any element of myArray.

```
<select>
<option value="8-17">8-17</option>
<option value="9-17">9-17</option>
</select >
```

It should be pushed in to my new Array

```
$("select").change(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray; i++) {
    var newArr = [];
    if (myArray[i].includes( $(this).val() ) === true) {
        newArr( myArray[i] );
        console.log(newArr.length);
    }
  }
});
```

Result should look like

```
var newArr = [
    ["9-15", "Text"],
    ["9-15", "Text"]
]
```

Comment: looks like you're using JQuery.

Comment: `newArr` is not a function... it's an array, you would do `newArr.push(value)`, not `newArr(value)`

Answer (score 0):

you had to compare to myArray.length, plus you had to add the item to newArr (since newArr isn't a function)

```
$("select").change(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var newArr = [];
    if (myArray[i].includes( $(this).val() ) === true) {
        newArr.push( myArray[i] );
        console.log(newArr.length);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myArray = [
  ["9-15", "Text"],
  ["9-15", "Text"],
  ["8-15", "Text"],
];

let chosenArray = [];

function elaborate(event) {
  let values = event.currentTarget.value.split('-');
  let chosenValue = myArray.find(findInTheArray.bind(null, values));
  // check that you already didn't add the selected value. To remove if you 
  // want duplicates too
  let isChosenValueAlreadyPresent = chosenArray.find(findInTheArray.bind(null, values));
  if (chosenValue && !isChosenValueAlreadyPresent) {
    chosenArray.push(chosenValue);
  }
  console.log(chosenArray);
}

function findInTheArray(values, el) {
  let ret = false;
  values.forEach(val => {
    if (el[0].indexOf(val) > -1) {
      ret = true;
    }
  });
  return ret;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="elaborate(event)">
  <option value="8-17">8-17</option>
  <option value="9-17">9-17</option>
</select>
```